# как добавить длину массива через параметр функции в C++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

```
void getArray(int lenArray) {


    int arr[lenArray];
    // ошибка требует что значение длины было константой, а мне надо передать длину именно
    //из параметра lenArray
}
```

Comment: Использовать динамически выделяемый массив (`int * arr = new int[lenArray]`) или вообще вектор...

Comment: `std::vector<int> arr; arr.resize(lenArray);`, хотя возможно push_back отработает заметно лучше

Comment: Или то же самое в одну строчку: `std::vector<int> arr(lenArray);`.

Comment: я  не люблю эту запись. в ней очень легко получить прикольную ошибку, когда указанная строка трактуется как объявление функции. И скорее всего, заранее выделять память не нужно.

Comment: Подобная аллокация массива на стеке разрешена, если собирать программу как C (не С++).

Comment: нужно, что бы компилятор поддерживал VLA. Студийный компилятор раньше точно так не умел (сейчас говорят, вроде научился, но только для си). gcc давно умеет (что обычно и портит жизнь юным студентам) даже для с++ режима.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов много.

```
int * arr = new int[lenArray];
```

Минус в том, что надо не забыть сделать `delete[]arr;`, иначе будет утечка памяти.

Если очень нужен именно массив в стеке? а тип при этом POD, можно прибегнуть к нестандарту в смысле С++, но имеющемуся по сути везде вызову `alloca`, который выделяет память в стеке, так что освобождать ее не надо:

```
int * arr = (int*)alloca(sizeof(int)*lenArray);
```

Ну и, наконец, самое логичное при использовании С++ решение — вектор (можно даже с инициализатором :)):

```
vector<int> arr(lenArray, initialValue);
```

`, initialValue` можно и опустить.

Стек особо не занимает, освобождать не надо... словом, можно просто использовать, и не думать об обслуживании.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид принятого ответа ("птица" слева от ответа).